# Convert a Map to an Object in Kotlin

Tags: java, json, firebase, object, kotlin

Hello guys I have a simple question ,
I have a Map full of element and I want to convert It in my Object , let me show you some code :

Here is my Object :

```
class Bundle(map: Map<String, Any>) {
    var version: String?
    var app: String?
    var countries: ArrayList<Any>?
    var currency: ArrayList<Any>?
    var force: Boolean?
    var name: String?
    var service: ArrayList<Any>?
    var money: Int?

    init {
        version= null
        app= null
        countries= arrayListOf()
        currency= arrayListOf<Any>()
        force= true
        name = ""
        service= arrayListOf<Any>()
        money= 0
    }
}
```

And there is the Map that i want to convert:

```
fun getBundle() {

    var db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val docRef = db.collection("aa").document("bb")

    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            val document = task.result
            if (document.exists()) {
                Log.d("Doc", "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.data!!)
              // Here i want to take (document.data!!) and convert it to my Bundle class

            } else {
                Log.d("NO doc", "No such document")
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("ERROR", "get failed with ", task.exception)
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: What is exactly the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: Can't be uglier.. Why `ArrayList<Any>?` with `= arrayListOf()`? Why so many `Any`s?

Comment: @hotkey The problem that i'm trying to solve is , how can I convert my map in my Bundle object

Comment: @ice1000 sorry about this I'm new in Kotlin , I thought it was the good way to initialize

Comment: Generally, you want to avoid `Any` and `?` as much as you can, the more specific you can be about a type, the less likely it is to not be what you expect when you go to use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok I found the solution

I transformed my Bundle class in a data class :

```
data class Bundle(
    var version: String? = null,
    var app: String? = null,
    var countries: ArrayList<Any> = arrayListOf(),
    var currency: HashMap<String, Any> = hashMapOf(),
    var force: Boolean = false,
    var name: String? = null,
    var service: ArrayList<Any> = arrayListOf(),
    var money: Int = 0
)
```

And then I simply added this on my method , where I want to convert my Map to my Bundle Object :

```
val myObject = document.toObject(Bundle::class.java)
```